# How to create an database or API in React and get all rows by axios or something?

Tags: reactjs, rest, api

I want to create a simple login in React, but I dunno how to keep form infos in something like MySQL database.

I tried to do an API in Express.js, but I get info when trying to send something:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/world' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

HandleClick function:

```js
handleClick(e) {
  let apiURL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
  $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
  $('.btn').html('<div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>');
  let payload = {
    "email": this.state.email,
    "password": this.state.password
  }
  Axios.post(apiURL + 'world', payload)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.data.code === 200) {
        console.log('Logged in!!!!');
      } else if (response.data.code === 204) {
        console.log('Bad pass');
        ('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.btn').html('Spróbuj jeszcze raz');
        $('#error').text('Bad pass');
      } else {
        console.log('No user');
        ('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.btn').html('Spróbuj jeszcze raz');
        $('#error').text('No user');
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
      $('.btn').html('Spróbuj jeszcze raz');
      $('#error').text(error);
    });
}
```

I want to have something where I can send informations and get them. Like CRUD.

Comment: I would prefer [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)

Comment: If you are running express server from same IP, you can add `proxy` property into project's package.json. [https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CORS middleware to allow different domains to use your Express app

1. `npm install cors`
2. Implement CORS middleware to allow your React App's domain to consume Express App's API

**index.js(Your Express app's main file)**

```js
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
...

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://yourreactappsdomain.com'
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

...
```

You can read [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/express-cors/) which is detailed about why you are facing this issue and how to solve it.